# Tab bar should show in all view controllers along with side menu

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, tabbar

I have to show tabbar in bottom of all viewcontroller in app, if user is navigate through side menu to different Viewcontrollers, still 4 bottom tab bar should show in bottom of app and also user can navigate through it to tabbar's child tabbar viewcontrolle and side menu vice versa. 
I tried to change root of app to main tabbar and then tried to push through child's navigation controller but did not succeed. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this tow tutorials will help https://fluffy.es/twitter-slide-menu-1/, https://fluffy.es/twitter-slide-menu-2/

Comment: Yes, you have done the right thing by setting the  tabbar as the root , and when you push any viewcontroller from tabbar's child view controller you must set the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed to false, then it won't hide the tabbar when any viewController is pushed in childviewcontrollers